# Links are not working

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags

I am creating a Webapp for a project, at the moment for prototyping purposes I am just hosting it on google drive.

https://googledrive.com/host/0B5gW3AYRbRMoYU5RaHpNS2ZEY3c/energize.html

If you click the top left "search" icon it should take you to another page called energizemap.html which it seems to do but without actually showing the content of that page as you can see if you go directly to the page the content is completely different.

https://googledrive.com/host/0B5gW3AYRbRMoYU5RaHpNS2ZEY3c/energizemap.html

Can anyone solve why this happens?

I have tried giving the  href as energizemap.html as well as the direct link i posted above.

here is the current code for the a link

```
<a href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B5gW3AYRbRMoYU5RaHpNS2ZEY3c/energizemap.html"><img class="imgLeft" src="search32.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Maps"/></a>
```

Comment: Has anyone got a response for this? still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with rel = "external" on every link that linked to another external page.